# Smooth scroll to the div when the page opens with hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS which works but then it starts to scroll before the page completes loading. Is there a way to check page loading and then load for that smooth effect?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var href = window.location.href+'#team';
    var splitit = (href.split('#'))[1];
    if(splitit !== "" || splitit !== "undefined"){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery('#'+splitit).offset().top - 50
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Also, what does `splitit` do? Can we remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
//result is array [How,are,you,doing,today?]
```

Remove for what?
Splitit needed for checking is in url '#'-symbol or not empty url after '#'.

Try load event that runs when the page is fully loaded including graphics.

```
jQuery( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For this functionality, you can utilize modern browsers css:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

but I recommend this approach: call smoothScroll() in document.ready

```
function smoothScroll(){
    // this part will add ID's to the named anchor tags
    // please name tags names not to interfere with other elements id's but 
    // also will look good in addressbar, as : #ListOfFeaturedProductsSection
    $("a").each(function(){
        var t=this;
        if (t.name!=="" && t.id==""){
            t.id=t.name;
        }
    });

  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {
    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      var hash = this.hash;
      if (hash) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        }, 800, function(){
            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

splitit is the id attribute of the target to what the page should be scrolled.

Actually it is not so obviously how to check that all resources are loaded, but you can put this jquery code in the end of your page before , i think, it helps you partly.